# Repeating Image Textures to UV map

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, uv-image-editor

At the moment I´m working on a model with many different Image Textures.
To publish it on Sketchfab I need UV Maps that fit the texture. 
My unwraped Object is however bigger then the texture itself.

How can I make a UV Map out of a repeating Image Texture?
Do I need to manually reapeat it in Photoshop unil it fits?

(I know that you can press **Ctrl+A** and **Ctrl+P** to make it fit to the texture. The mappping changes though)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try pressing S after highlighting your mesh in the UV editor to scale it downward. There should also be a repeat image setting somewhere in the UV editor.

Comment: To add on to this, after you press S you can press z, x, and y to lock the scaling directions (which would be very helpful in OPs case)